# How to call Karate-defined function from Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, karate

The scenario looks like this: Assume we have a helloworld.feature file that contains a scenario of just `* print "Hello World!"`

Then in another feature we do:

```
Scenario: call karate function from js
  * def foo = read('helloworld.feature')
  * def bar = 
  """
  function(){ foo() }
  """

  * bar()
  # or even * call bar
```

This will throw an exception. I've also tried `karate.get("foo")` to get the variable from karate scope and then try to call the result, same issue.

`* foo()` works fine, however.

Is this possible? Why or why not?

The upswing seems to be that, if you've defined a "feature function" in karate (i.e. using `def x = read()`), and you want to call the same feature in JS, you have to **re**-define the function again in JS.

Answer (score 0):

When a feature is loaded, it is NOT JS, and the only thing you can do is `call` it.

```
* def foo = read('helloworld.feature')
* call foo
```

If you want to use conditional logic (or mix this into JS functions), note that `karate.call()` will also work:

```
* karate.call('helloworld.feature')
```